# Git и GitHub на windows от новичка (часть 2)

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-key

1. Что такое публичный и приватный ssh-ключ? Эта пара ключей для одного пользователя? Если так, то для каждого пользователя я должен в настройки GitHub-а сохранить его публичный ключ? Или достаточно одного публичного ключа для всех?
2. Зачем нужен пароль (passphrase) для соединения по ssh к репозиторию на GitHub? Этот пароль нужен только для доступа к паре ssh ключей, которые хранятся в папке `~/.ssh` (`имя_пользователя/.shh`)? Или этот пароль так же знает репозиторий на GitHub?
3. Пара ключей ssh хранится в папке пользователя на винде. Если я захочу присоединиться к другому репозиторию по ssh, то значит мне надо будет изменить эту пару ssh ключей?
4. Если удалить ветку, то удаляться и все его коммиты? Хотя если подумать, то ветка это всего лишь указатель на коммит, значит удалится этот указатель, а не сами коммиты. Так?
5. Я уже запутался с этими командами `перехода_на_коммит`/`изменения_коммита`/`удаления_коммитов` и т. п. Какие именно команды удаляют коммиты навсегда, а не просто из виду убирают? `reset` (soft/hard)? `revert`? еще что-нибудь?
6. Как сделать так, чтобы перестало просить пароль при использовании ssh соединения? Например, когда использую `git push` или `git fetch`.
7. MS Visual Studio 2010 создал файл `main.cpp`. При попытки его (и другие файлы с кодом от MS VS) индексировать выводится ошибка:

   > Fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in main.cpp.

   Искал в гугле и что-то было про это, но как решить эту проблему я не понял.

Comment: Вы не из тех людей, которые в магазине спрашивают продавца, где именно включается плеер?

Comment: Это вы к чему?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) Что такое публичный и приватный ssh-ключ?

Сгенерированная пара текстов позволяющих шифровать и расшифровывать данные. Также можно использовать как идентификатор пользователя (правда длинный).

> Эта пара ключей для одного пользователя?

Да. Один пользователь может иметь много ключей. (Один для рабочего компа, один для ноута, ...)

> Если так, то для каждого пользователя я должен в настройки GitHub'а сохранить его публичный ключ? Или достаточно одного публичного ключа для всех?

Насколько мне известно github не позволяет использовать один и тот же ключ в нескольких аккаунтах. Придётся генерировать пару для каждого аккаунта.

> 2) Зачем нужен пароль(passphrase) для соединения по ssh к репозиторию на GitHub?

Чтобы повысить уровень защиты. Оберегает доступ в случае кражи приватного ключа.

> Этот пароль нужен только для доступа к паре ssh ключей, которые хранятся в папке ~/.ssh(имя_пользователя/.shh)? Или этот пароль так же знает репозиторий на GitHub?

Этот пароль никакого отношения к github не имеет, только к ключу. Указывается в момент генерации ключа.

> 3)Пара ключей ssh хранится в папке пользователя на винде. Если я захочу присоединиться к другому репозиторию по ssh, то значит мне надо будет изменить эту пару ssh ключей?

Нет. Ключи используются для доступа к серверу с определённого компьютера. Можно сгенерировать пару, и использовать её для доступа к github, bitbucket, какие-то свои сервера. Ну и добавив ключ в настройках аккаунта вы пользуетесь им для работы со всеми репозиториями которые предоставляет сервис.

> 4) Если удалить ветку, то удаляться и все его коммиты? Хотя если подумать, то ветка это всего лишь указатель на коммит, значит удалится этот указатель, а не сами коммиты. Так?

Не знаю точно. По идее не должны, однако в git используется процедура сжатия, во время которой они могут быть удалены. На SO рекомендуют добавлять тег для ветки (для последнего коммита) и удалять её, тогда коммиты останутся и ветка не будет мозолить глаза.

> 5)Я уже запутался с этими командами перехода_на_коммит/изменения_коммита/удаления_коммитов и т.п. Какие именно команды удаляют коммиты навсегда, а не просто из виду убирают? reset(soft/hard)? revert? еще что-нибудь?

`revert` не удаляет, лишь обращает изменения новым коммитом.

По-вопросу: не знаю, мне всегда хватало `reset`.

> 6)Как сделать так, чтобы перестало просить пароль при использовании ssh соединения? Например, когда использую git push или git fetch.

Сгенерировать новый ключ, во время ввода пароля ничего не вводить.

> 7)MS Visual Studio 2010 создал файл main.cpp. При попытки его(и другие файлы с кодом от MS VS) индексировать ошибка: Fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in main.cpp. Искал в гугле и что-то было про это, но как решить эту проблему я не понял.

Windows-specific problem. По-идее ничего страшного, на SO предлагают добавить

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
```

сижу на линуксах, поэтому тут помочь не могу.

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:**

> А что если через один аккаунт, но на разных компьютерах или пользователей в винде?

можно сгенерить новый ключ, и добавить его как второй в настройках аккаунта.

> Т.е. я могу использовать одну пару ключей для любых репозиториев? И вообще все, что угодно(что работает через ssh)?

Да.

> > Ну и добавив ключ в настройках аккаунта вы пользуетесь им для работы со всеми репозиториями которые предоставляет сервис.
> > Все репозитории одного аккаунта вы имели ввиду?

Да.

Comment: >Насколько мне известно github не позволяет использовать один и тот же ключ в нескольких аккаунтах. Придётся генерировать пару для каждого аккаунта.

А что если через один аккаунт, но на разных компьютерах или пользователей в винде?

>Нет. Ключи используются для доступа к серверу с определённого компьютера. 

Т.е. я могу использовать одну пару ключей для любых репозиториев? И вообще все, что угодно(что работает через ssh)?

>Ну и добавив ключ в настройках аккаунта вы пользуетесь им для работы со всеми репозиториями которые предоставляет сервис.

Все репозитории одного аккаунта вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Насчет ошибки, оказывается я не внимательно посмотрел в инструкции и написал для mac/unix, а для винды надо:
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.safecrlf true

Comment: Да, `reset` удаляет коммиты. `--soft` оставляет изменения, но удаляет сами коммиты. `--hard` удаляет насовсем.